# Edittext in listview not showing soft keyboard

Tags: android-layout

I used edittext in listview item.But it not working properly even though setting activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan".Is there any way to solve this problem.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: you add android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" on your activity holding the listview?

Comment: yes,I tried that but still not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your view.
**android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"**

Comment: I know it's an old answer but could you please specify which view I should add this attribute to?

Answer (score 0):

If the layout is displayed without an EditText, it does not load the keyboard, paste this at the beginning of your layout.

```
    <EditText
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    ... 
    <ListView ...
```